# HTTP Error -999 when loading UIWebView in new viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

The following objective C code fails on click with error message "HTTP Task failed (Error code: -999). It works when UIWebView is loaded in the current viewController, so it doesn't have to do with the links. This breaks both on phone and simulator.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSString *urlString = [_array_url objectAtIndex:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog([_array_url objectAtIndex:recognizer.view.tag]);
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    UIViewController *avc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleView"];
    [avc.view addSubview:webview];
    [webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: have you try to stop ongoing request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works when UIWebView is loaded in the current viewController

So if this *doesn't* work, then *don't do it:*

```
UIViewController *avc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleView"];
[avc.view addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
```

You're breaking all the rules here:

- You must NOT SPEAK of another view controller's *view* just after creating it. The view has not been loaded, and you are forcing it to load prematurely.
- You must NOT alter another view controller's interface directly.
- You must NOT force the url request load to start before the view controller is even part of the view controller hierarchy.

Everything you're doing here is wrong. That is NOT how you talk to a view controller!

Instead, just give ArticleViewController a `request` *property*:

```
ArticleViewController *avc = (ArticleViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleView"];
avc.request = urlRequest;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
```

*That* is what you are allowed to do when you create a view controller: you can set a property. That's all! And now ArticleViewController can add the web view to *its own view* and load the request, in its own `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: ah, I see. Thank you.